Chain Mudfish VPN with private Wireguard node
The problem I am trying to solve is high ping in a Quake Live server located in China, Shenzhen. I am located in Osaka. This is obviously not a critical issue, however I wanted to experiment a bit for fun.
When I connect without VPN my ping is 330, literally unplayable. When using Mudfish (using the Sakuranet 6 node) the ping is 80. I am trying to improve the ping on the Shenzhen server to be less than 60.
To solve this issue I decided to try creating my own VPN node in the Shenzhen area. I bought a 1-core 2GB 1Mbps VM located in Guangzhou Zone 6 on Tencent. I set up Wireguard and I can connect correctly to the VPN server from my Windows gaming machine.
When connecting to the QL server with my private VPN, I get an improvement: from 330 it goes down to 290.
Now the idea is to chain the Mudfish VPN with my private node so that I can ideally benefit from that -40 ping improvement, resulting in a ping around 40/50 when connecting to the Shenzhen server.
I tried playing around with ChatGPT and doing what it suggests, but without much luck. When activating both VPNs it just doesn't work at all (when trying to ping the QL server from Windows prompt it says "General error").
I am by no means an expert in how networks work, so I am just wondering if my idea makes any sense and what is my best bet to improve the ping.
I am also setting up my account on Alibaba, which appears to have servers right in Shenzhen, so that I could potentially decrease my ping further.
To summarize the idea is to achieve something like:
Mudfish nodes -> my private VPN node -> game server
Does anyone have any suggestions? What are my alternatives here?
